# How to get JSON Elements from String(full with JSON object).

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, apache-kafka

I have a JSON file

```
{ "impressions":
        [
          {
            "impressionId": "7ad7a77fas346a7a2a1da6",
            "userId": "hafsa",
            "clientId": "400"
          },
          {
            "impressionId": "7ad7a77fas346a7a2a1da7",
            "userId": "asif",
            "clientId": "200"
          },
          {
            "impressionId": "7ad7a77fas346a7a2a1da8",
            "userId": "zadarov",
            "clientId": "300"
          },
          {
            "impressionId": "7ad7a77fas346a7a2a1da9",
            "userId": "julia",
            "clientId": "100"
          }
        ]
}
```

I am working on Kafka and have a NodeJS Producer and Java Consumer.I have to get each impression as a separate message in my consumer. My nodeJS code is:

```
console.log("Kafka is recieving JSON....");
var fs = require('fs');
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var Producer = kafka.Producer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var client = new Client('localhost:2181');
var producer = new Producer(client);


fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;


    var jsonobj = JSON.parse(data);
    var countMessages = jsonobj.impressions.length;
    var impressionArr = [];
    impressionArr = jsonobj.impressions;
    payloads = [
        { topic: 'test', messages: impressionArr, partition: 0 }
    ];
    producer.on('ready', function(){
        producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){

            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    producer.on('error', function(err){
        console.log("Error: "+err)
    });


});
```

and my JAVA consumer is :

```
JavaInputDStream<String> messagesFrmSpecifiedOffset= KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                sc,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                String.class,
                kafkaParams,
                fromOffset,
                new Function<MessageAndMetadata<String, String>, String>() {
                    public String call(MessageAndMetadata<String, String> msgAndMd) throws Exception {

                        return msgAndMd.message();
                    }
                }

        );
```

and I am getting impressions as separate messages as follows in JAVA consumer.

```
JavaDStream<Record> rdd_impressionRecords = messagesFrmSpecifiedOffset.map(
                new Function<String, Record>() {
                    public Record call(String impressions) throws Exception {

                        System.out.println("impressions: " + impressions);

                        Record sd = new Record();
                        return sd;
                    }
                });
```

BUT MY PROBLEM IS:
that I am getting output in object form like:

```
impressions: [object Object]
impressions: [object Object]
impressions: [object Object]
impressions: [object Object]
```

I know that I am sending JSON and recieving as String but anyone can help me to do solution in three ways:
1. Can I get key, values from [object Object] in Java class.
2. Is it possible to send each array element as String (using JSON.stringify) in NodeJS without any loop. Direct transfer as I am doing.
3. Can I rewrite method of createDirectStream that returns JSON obect directly.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Zdeněk Tisoň answer:

a) First use **JSON.stringify()** to create a string and send it over the net.

b) At the consumers side transform this string to whatever you want. If you want it to be Json you can use **JSON.parse()**.

Comment: Worked Well for me with above two steps.

Answer (score 1):

Client code could be:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var payloads = _.map(JSON.parse(data).impressions, function(imp){
  return JSON.stringify(imp); 
});
producer.send(payloads, function(err, data){

});
```

Spark code could use json-simple library:

```
import org.json.simple.*;
JSONObject imp = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(impression);
String impressionId = (String) imp.get("impressionId");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Java's JSONObject to get the string as a JSONObject like so:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(impressions)
```

Then use the JSONObject functions to get what you need as listed here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Comment: Actually it cannot run, bcz JSONObject is reading  [object Object], not a JSON string. Is there any way to access object values in impressions or any way to convert into JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify before sending messages onto the Kafka bus. For example, your code changes to messages: JSON.stringify(impressionArr).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK producing object to kafka is not supported by kafka-node. If you try to do that, the object itself would be in format of [object Object], actually it's String '[object Object]'. That's why you can not de-serialize from Java.
try `JSON.stringify(impressionArr)` when produce in your node code and some JSON library when consume from Java side.